# LED driver not responsive

Tags: led, driver

I've got a number of HEF4794 BP LED drivers (8-stage shift-and-store register LED driver) daisy-chained together to drive LEDs from a microcontroller. The outputs of the drivers are connected to a fairly long wire (~2m), then the LED, then a 330R resistor and finally to +5V supply. Thus a zero at the output lights up the LED.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes, when I haven't turned the LEDs on for a while, there seems to be a charge on these wires which prevents the LEDs from being switched by the driver. This seems to occur by driver, not by output line. When I put my hand on the solder points at the PCB where the drivers are soldered to (supposedly grounding some wires), the drivers are set back to the way they are supposed to work.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? I tried to hold my fingers on the output line, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Schematic:

[image]

The microcontroller and driver are connected to a common ground and the MCU runs on 3.3V and the driver on 5V (the digital inputs of the driver are 3V tolerant, so that shouldn't be an issue).

[image]

Comment: Have you done any measurements with a multimeter to verify wether the outputs actually are stuck in this state? And please provide a schematic of your setup :)

Comment: No, I haven't actually measured anything. It's quite a transient state - I don't think I could measure much with a multimeter (which is all I have available). I provided the schematic.

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't seem to affect all LED drivers. Some work fine, some "need to be touched" to work...

Comment: I don't see any ground connection between your modules. Have you supplied a correct and complete schematic?

Comment: Is your MCU powered from +5 and with a common ground?

Comment: _”No, I haven't actually measured anything”_ As an EE, this should be your very first thing to do in almost any situation. A transient state is the very thing an oscilloscope is made for capturing.

Comment: Is the LED driver powered by 5V? Is the MCU powered by 5V? Or 3.3V? Is there ground between MCU and driver? Is this built on a breadboard or PCB? How is it built, where are the schematics, PCB layout etc?

Comment: Driver runs on 5V, MCU on 3.3V and both are connected to a common ground.

Comment: @winny "A transient state is the very thing an oscilloscope is made for capturing" yes, but as I said, I don't have access to one. My multimeter won't capture that...

Comment: @Justme components are in soldered sockets on a PCB (connected with patch wires).

Comment: @orange I wonder if there are bypass caps on the design? Can't you post the actual schematics instead of some non-detailed block diagram which basically tells almost nothing? Or a photo of the device how it is built?

Comment: @Justme No caps, there's not much to see from the PCB (lots of wires and soldering points). I don't have schematics apart from the above...

Comment: I looked at your circuit -- thanks for the picture, by the way.  There is a large mass of green wires going to one junction, and a large mass of red wires, also going to a large junction. Both junctions look like they might have cold solder joints, or otherwise, a questionable connection. Maybe it was very cold that day you soldered. Measure the resistance between each wire and a master one from the group, to see if you can identify the problem first, for your own self-edification. Then resolder those questionable connections. Use lots of flux, and make sure it's shiny. Heat gun area if needed

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Thanks for looking at the picture. I measured the resistance and found that the resistance is as much as the cable (~0.1Ohms). The solder joints may look cold because I used Pb free solder (they tend to look a bit less glossy, but are ok).

Answer (score 1):

When the driver supply voltage is 5V, it may not work with the 3.3V logic levels from MCU properly.

It sure is tolerant to 3.3V signals but can't reliably distinguish logic high, as datasheet says 3.5V is minimum acceptable voltage for logic high.

That may not be the only problem, but so far only we know.

Comment: Interesting - I had thought that VIH is <= 3.3V, but upon reviewing the datasheet again, I found it is 3.5V as you say. Would that explain the intermittent behaviour for some of the drivers (different drivers exhibit the behaviour at different times)? Would a pull-up resistor on CLK and MOSI resolve this?

Comment: No, because the MCU IO pins can only work with up to the MCU supply voltage of 3.3V, you can't pull them any more up with resistors to 5V, that will exceed the IO pin safe voltage rating and starts to inject current from 5V supply via the MCU to 3.3V supply. Also, having no bypass capacitors on the chips may be one  cause why it does not work. Or the wire wrapping, it's not optimal for signals with fast edges like MCU outputs.

Comment: So that bypass capacitor would go on the 3.3V and 5V voltage supply? As for the SPI voltage levels, would you recommend a left shifter IC?

Comment: I meant to write "level shifter"

Comment: "That bypass"? That is why we asked for the actual schematics what is on the design and what is not, so a simplified block diagram is of no use. If you have no capacitors on power supplies on that board, it's time to start putting them in now. Typically, you put one bypass cap right next to each chip. Especially on a wire-wrap designs with high frequencies. Some amount of bulk capacitance here and there, especially at the supply input to the board, would not hurt either. Just connect the board to 3.3V supply first, to see if it is a problem of level shifting or not.

Comment: Ok, I'll add 1 cap per driver. What capacity do you recommend?

Comment: "Just connect the board to 3.3V supply first, to see if it is a problem of level shifting or not." What do you mean? The MCU is connected to 3.3V and the drivers to 5V. Are you suggesting to connect the drivers to 3.3V as well?

Comment: @orange sorry I remembered someone already suggested using 3.3V for the LED driver, apparently I was wrong. Yes, if the 3.3V and 5V device are incompatible due to supply voltages, why is the 5V device on 5V to begin with, if they both could be on 3.3V supply.  Does anything prevent using 3.3V for the whole thing?

Comment: I'll try to use a 3.3V power supply instead. I initially used the 5V from a USB port (the MCU has a separate 3.3V regulator which is too weak for all the LEDs).

Comment: @orange A quick glance at Philips dataseet gives an impression you can use 5V for LEDs and 3.3V for the chip. Which would make sense since it is an open collector driver. But feel free to double check yourself from different datasheets.

Comment: I've tried to run it with a power bank which has lower voltage and a USB outlet (4.6V) which also provides less than the power adapter (5.3V) that I am using. I couldn't observe the behaviour with any of the lower voltage power sources... I keep monitoring the issue. Thanks for your help.